# Insert pdf to the beginning

Tags: xetex, pdfpages

Using pdfpages when I add a pdf like

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,draft]{book}
\usepackage{log}
\newfontfamily\dejavu{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}
%-----------------------------Cover Page----------------------------------------

\includepdf{Cover/cover}
```

it just prints 'Cover/cover' to the page (see the picture)

picture: [image]

Thus, my question: How to solve this right?

Comment: `pdfpages` works like `graphics` with the option demo you will never get any pictures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `draft` class option; change

```
 \documentclass[10pt,twoside,draft]{book}
```

to

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
```